# How to access a function from sibling component in blazor?

Tags: blazor

I have two different components, one isn't nested in the other, they are seperate, but will be seen at the same time in the same layout.

**Component 1**

```
@code {
    public void Tester()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("worked");
    }
}
```

**Component 2**

```
@code {
    Component1 c1 = new Component1();

     c1.Tester();
}
```

component 2 insists that **c1.Tester()** does not exist.

Is there a way around this so that I can access the Tester function in component 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to c1.Tester() should of course be inside a method:

```
@code {
    Component1 c1 = new Component1();

  void SomeMethod()
  {
     c1.Tester();   // this should work
  }
}
```

If this is not it then post the exact code and literal error message.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `@ref` to get `Component1` method and pass it as a parameter to `Component2`

```
<Component1 @ref="Component1Ref" />
<Component2 Tester="@Tester" />

@code {
    Component1 Component1Ref;

    void Tester()
    {
        Component1Ref.Tester();
    }
}
```

Here is a [working example](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/t57ru00d).